# Session is lost in apache after nginx proxy switch

Tags: apache, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am building a docker which i can use for my work. I am using MacOS. If I create docker container with xdebug installed (Ubuntu 16, php7.2, xdebug, apache), code execution is extremely slow even if i am not listening to xdebug port. I have already get rid of 'mounts'.
So I decided to created something like this:

[docker structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbpC3.png)

And everything works just like i want. When i change cookie in browser, my wesbite works fast, but when i change cookie to another one, i am able to debug. But i am facing a problem that it logs out me when i change that cookie value and nginx proxies me to another server. (Each apache is a single docker container with ubuntu and apache)

So my question is if there is a workaround for this so I could share session between server that I don't get logged out? Or at least any ideas what needs to be changed in that scheme.

P.S. My project is Magento 2 and probably the source of an issue is in this one. But i actually don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

According to  https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/load-balancing/, the sticky session is a feature of nginx plus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That looks like something interesting but i feel like it wouldn't help because it would send cookie to the same server, but I feel like i need exactly cookie sharing between two containers. I might be wrong.

Comment: then what you need is session replication/clustering.